# Print dataframes from a list where length(df) is greater than 4

Tags: r

Trying to print all dataframes of a list where length(df) is greater than 4. I've been trying this with no luck:

```
## dummy data from Zelazny7
list1 <- list(mtcars[1:10, ], mtcars[1:2,], mtcars)

sapply(list1, function(x) {
    if(length(x) > 4) { list1 <- x }
})
```

Comment: If these are dataframes, make sure you really want to use `length` and not `nrow`.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand "dataframes" do you mean "columns" instead?

Comment: `Filter(function(x) nrow(x) > 4, list1)`

Comment: @rawr I didn't saw your comment.  Anyway, deleted my answer.  Please consider to post that as answer.

Answer (score 4):

#### some dummy data

```
list1 <- list(mtcars[1:10, ], mtcars[1:2,], mtcars)
```

#### Simply index the list where nrows > 4:

```
list1[sapply(list1, nrow) > 4]
```